# can't find iOS app main target symbol file after upload to itunesconnect with bitcode open

Tags: ios, xcode

I uploaded my app to itunesconnect with bitcode open, and I use CocoaPods to manage dependencies and Fabric to crash analysis.

But Fabric tell me that missing REQUIRED dSYMs, so I download symbols from itunesconnect, but I do not find required dsym file, all other pod dsyms are there.

Which compile flags I set that make this happen? or any clue can help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on your `archive -> Show in Finder ->` Right click on file and click on `Show package contents`.

Here you will find your .dSYM file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Build Settings` -> `Debug Information Format` and change it to `DWARF with dSYM File`

Then try upload again.